# Hide a `tr` based on the values of `td` in the table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table that is filled with dynamic content from a query from a database on the backend. I want to hide any `tr` that contains only zeros.

Here is what my table looks like:

```
<table id="table1" " cellspacing="0" style="width: 800px">
<thead id="tablehead">
</thead>
<tbody id="tabledata">
<tr class="odd">
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0.00%</td>
<td>0.00%</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
<td>$0.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now if the first three `td`'s in `tbody` are `==` 0 then I would like to add a class to the `tr` that will effectively hide that row. How would I go about doing this using jQuery?

***EDIT:***
Sorry forgot to add what I have tried. The following is a test script I tried to see if I could collect all the `td`'s

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table1 td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text == 0;
    }).css("text-color", "red");

    });
```

Comment: Added what I tried. Sorry forgot to put that up.

Comment: What is `.css("text-color"`?

Comment: @Ian I just wanted to see if the `filter` function would select the correct `td`'s

Comment: @NicYoung Yes, but `text-color` is not a style. I think you meant for `color`?

Comment: And in your code, you'd want to use `.text()`, not `.text`...and probably compare to `"0"` not `0`, although I'm guessing the comparison would still work since you're using `==`

Comment: @Ian Ah, I see. Thanks! I am still very new to JS.

Comment: @NicYoung No problem, just trying to help through the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914296/javascript-regular-expressions-with-jquery-contains-regex-extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    if (tr.find('td:eq(0)').text()=="0"
        && tr.find('td:eq(1)').text()=="0"
        && tr.find('td:eq(2)').text()=="0"
    ) tr.addClass('hidden');
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/XULmA/) (the hidden class changes the color to red, it's clearer...)

Depending on your need, you might have to [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the texts, or to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) them.

For more complex tests, you might find useful to work directly with an array of the cell contents. You can get it using

```
var celltexts = tr.find('td').map(function(){return $(this).text()}).toArray();
```